# lazyLoading CollectionView with activity indicator

Tags: ios, uiimage, uicollectionview, uiactivityindicatorview

My issue is i'm getting activity indicator after image loaded but it should appear before image is loaded .i'm using SDWebImageProgressivedownload code but activity indicator is loading after image is displaying.please help me

```
__block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator =    [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:activityStyle];
activityIndicator.center = imageView.center;
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                    success:^(UIImage *image) { [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview]; }
failure:^(NSError *error) { [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview]; }];

[imageView addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that you are adding a UIActivityIndicatorView on a cell that might get dequed and reused later on before your block triggers.

To fix this, make the activity indicator a property of your cell:

```
@interface Cell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView activityIndicator;

@end
```

In your implementation

```
@implementation Cell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    [self initialize];
}
return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[super awakeFromNib];
[self initialize];
}

- (void)initialize
{
// This code is only called once
self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
self.activityIndicator.center = self.photoOneImageView.center;
self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[self.photoOneImageView addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
}

@end
```

Then in your cellForItemAtIndex method

```
[cell.photoOneImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://somesite.com/pic.jpg"] 
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"] 
                             completed:
^(UIImage *image, NSError *error,  SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}];

[cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

I guess it should work

Answer (score 0):

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) recommend this category for [adding a progress indicator](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage)

Good luck